# ASP.Net WebAPI OWIN: Why would Request.GetOwinContext() return null?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

In my production code we're having a problem where Request.GetOwinContext() always returns null.

I setup a small test WebAPI controller to try and isolate the problem:

```
    public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsyncContext(string provider)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() == null)
            return this.BadRequest("No HttpContext.Current Owin Context");

        if (Request.GetOwinContext() == null)
            return this.BadRequest("No Owin Context");

        return this.Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetContext(string provider)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() == null)
            return this.BadRequest("No HttpContext.Current Owin Context");

        if (Request.GetOwinContext() == null)
            return this.BadRequest("No Owin Context");

        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```

At first I thought it might have something to do with the action method running asynchronously, but after running the above, it turns out that in both versions, Request.GetOwinContext() returns null.

I am using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin.5.1.1 (which is where it seems the GetOwinContext() extension method is defined).

Any ideas on what's happening here???

Comment: Are you certain the startup class is being called and all the modules are being registered?

Answer (score 16):

Another cause (especially after upgrading form ASP.NET MVC4 and / or Empty WebApi Template) is missing Startup.cs file in the root of WebAPI project.

Also, make sure that you have installed Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TestMVC5.Startup))]

namespace TestMVC5
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fix for me was installing `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` with Nuget.

Comment: don`t fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered similar issue. To fix this make sure below lines (with call to method **CreatePerOwinContext**) are there in your **Startup.Auth.cs** file in **ConfigureAuth**

method.

Your method may look like

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //   consumerKey: "",
        //   consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //   appId: "",
        //   appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");
    }
```

Comment: ApplicationRoleManager dose not exist in current context