# Access Current OwinContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I’m working on an OWIN hosted ASP.Net WebApi2 Microservice. We are using Autofac as Dependency Injector.

When my service gets called I can get information about the user by accessing owinContext.Request.User.Identity. My problem is when I have to make a call to another service and pass the user information along. I have to create an authorization token that includes the user information and set that token to the RequestMessage.

I would like to write a DelegatingHandler that I can put in the “HttpClient-MessageHandler-Pipline”. But inside DelegatingHandler.SendAsync() I would need to have access to the current OwinContext.

I thought about different approaches. But I really hope there is something easier and less error prone (or maybe a hint how I could make one of this approach feasible):

1. With Autofac I can’t easily solve the Captive Dependency Problem: The HttpClient and therefore the DelegatingHandler are registered as SingleInstance. But the OwinContext is registered on a LifeTimeScope. So I can’t just inject the OwinContext to the constructor of the DelegatingHandler.
2. I could write an Owin-Middleware that sets the OwinContext on a static System.Threading.AsyncLocal variable. Inside the DelegatingHandler I could access that static variable. But mutable global variables just feels really wrong to me.
3. I don’t write a DelegatingHandler at all. Inside my ServiceRepository (that can also be registered on the LifeTimeScope) I would have to construct all the RequestMessages by hand. Then it would be easy to set the AuthorizationToken onto the RequestMessage. But not using the convenience methods like e.g. httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync() brings a lot of work with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
                    IOwinContext owinContext = request.GetOwinContext();

                    // do something with the response and owinContext

                    return response;
                },
            cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wrote the following SendAsync Method:
{
var owinContextBeforeSend = request.GetOwinContext(); 
var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken); 
var owinContextAfterSend = request.GetOwinContext(); 
return response;
}
Unfortunately owinContextBeforeSend and owinContextAfterSend are both null. (And I would need owinContextBeforeSend.)

Comment: This approach probably can't work: There are 3 parties involved "SomeClient ---> MyService ---> SomeOtherService". Having a DelegatingHandler on the "server side", i.e. when recieving calls comming from SomeClient, there would be an OwinContext on the RequestMessage. But my DelegatingHandler is used on the "client side", i.e. to make a request to SomeOtherService. On the "client side" there is no Owin involved, therefore request.GetOwinContext() will return null.

Comment: I've tried your first `SendAsync` and not getting null owinContexes. How are you setting up Owin? Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252251/asp-net-webapi-owin-why-would-request-getowincontext-return-null ; the project I tried on: https://github.com/petreturcu/CodePractice/tree/master/Practice/ExtendingWebApi

Comment: The links you posted describe the problem of getting the OwinContext on "the server side" of my application. But that is not my problem, i don't have to get the OwinContext from an incomming HttpRequestMessage. I'm working on "the other side" of the microservice where I send an HttpRequestMessage to another service.